# Restore WSL2 after performing "Reset this PC" with "Keep my files"

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I've had to reset Windows to a blank slate using the *Keep my files* option, and I lost my WSL instance, forgetting to create a backup/export of the WSL instance prior to resetting the PC *(the files are still in my User Profile, but WSL itself doesn't recognize them anymore)*.

Is there any way to remount the WSL instance in my fresh copy of Windows after making sure WSL, Docker, and Hyper-V are enabled in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest doing it like this:

1. Install a dummy distribution of the same Linux version
2. Shutdown WSL2 with `wsl --shutdown`
3. Replace the `ext4.vhdx` file of the new distribution with your previous one

   - The installation folder of a distribution is typically stored
     in a folder named similar to (to avoid confusion, I suggest finding where the old `ext4.vhdx` is located before installing the new one):

     ```
     %LocalAppData%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState
     ```

Comment: That file seems to not have survived the Windows Reset :(.

Comment: @jessehouwing - That means your WSL instance was lost.

Comment: I was afraid of that ..

Comment: Have you located the folder, or has it disappeared ?

Comment: It disappeared.

Comment: Unless you can find a backup of the `.vhdx` file, this is a lost cause.